Why duplicated addresses in lookup table
I was looking at the Lookup Table 3t6q9eS6Hx1xbaA6MF7T5ujuuK2Tc7RUQ14QUxEHgrur, which I found by calling a swap endpoint in Jupiter.
I noticed that some keys are duplicated, like the TokenProgram in the screenshot.
What is the point of having duplicated addresses in a lookup table?


There's no reason to duplicate table entries. Likely it just makes things easier for Jupiter's tooling that created the lookup table accounts.
